# "Create New" text box in GWT radio button group

Tags: gwt, radio-button

In my GWT app I have a radio button group of choices. The last choice is to add a new item. What I want is that the words "create new xyz" to disappear, and to be replaced with a text box to take the input. What is the best way to do this? I have thought about using a disclosure panel, but that seems unnatural and I don't have it working properly yet.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to write an onClickHandler for that radio button? If so, then inside that onClickHandler, add code to generate the textbox.

Comment: Of course, but how do I replace the radio text with a text box?